# How can one syntax highlight and format GraphQL queries on an HTML page with C# on .NET Core / Blazor?

Tags: c#, html, .net-core, graphql, blazor-server-side

Basically what the title says; I would like to syntax highlight aka colourize the GraphQL queries like they do it in the "GraphiQL Explorer", and print it on an HTML page with .NET Core using C#. Im working with Blazor, so the pages are .razor.

See this screenshot:

[image]

And I also want to auto-format the queries so that the queries aren't on a single line, but with line-breaks and indentations as the button "prettify" does in the "GraphiQL explorer".

So here's a sample.

Convert this => `{human(id: "1000") {name height(unit: FOOT)}}`

to this =>

[image]

Edit:
Here's a blazorFiddle i created. [BlazorFiddleSample](https://blazorfiddle.com/s/vqp81utp)
Basically format\indent the graphql queries in a component page like this converter does, [freetooldev](http://freetool.dev/graphql-formatter)

Comment: marc_s: thanks for the edits.

Comment: [PrismJS](https://prismjs.com/) supports GraphQL and will handle the colour highlighting, and you could use the options to JSON.stringify() to format the JSON.

Comment: John M: will PrismJS actually color highlight my graphql queries (not json)?

And i was actually looking for a way to format(line break and indent properly) the graphql queries, not the json returned

Comment: John M: so I tried the PrismJS, and it seems to not work properly with the Blazor web app I'm working with. Basically what happens is, when the page is loading, the code gets highlighted for 1-2seconds, then suddenly it loses its colourization. I think it's because blazor isn't finished loading everything, and when it's done, it somehow overwrites the PrismJS highlighting.

Comment: John M: so i got the PrismJS kind of working. The colorization isnt perfect, it probably needs some tweaking, had to inject IJSRuntime, and then invoke the PrismJs inside the OnAfterRenderAsync. Basically what this guy does https://blog.ladeak.net/posts/blazor-code-highlight

Comment: Good news, thanks for the info

Comment: still looking for a way to indent\format my graphql query, got any suggestions ?

Comment: It would be helpful to see your code

Comment: https://blazorfiddle.com/s/vqp81utp 
here's a simple sample where I have 2 graphql queries on a component page.
Now i want to format the query and indent it like this converter does https://www.freetool.dev/graphql-formatter

Answer (score 0):

This could be achieved using **BlazorMonaco**

https://github.com/serdarciplak/BlazorMonaco

the code setup should look like this for the options

```
private StandaloneEditorConstructionOptions EditorConstructionOptions(MonacoEditor editor)
{
    return new StandaloneEditorConstructionOptions
    {
        AutomaticLayout = true,
        Language = "graphql",
    };
}
```

please follow the instructions to get it setup if this is something you want to try.

you can get more info on the use of Monaco Editor here:

https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/

Comment: oh nice, thanks, let me check it out, and come back to you

Comment: checked it out, it dosnt seems to be what i wanted. Im looking for something like what this site does: https://www.freetool.dev/graphql-formatter